# Change direction of voltage source arrow in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, DIV=15]{scrartcl}
% Zeichnen
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[european, scale=1]
        \draw
            (0,0) to [voltage source, v=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
            (0,2)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: outputOfCode]

How do I change the direction of the arrow without changing coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: real name or display name? what is user name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine the direction of the arrow, the package takes into account how the path has been set up.

In the current case you draw the path from `(0,0)` towards `(0,2)` hence the arrow points to the last coordinate. To have it in the other direction, thus you may want to use:

```
\draw
    (0,2) to [voltage source, v=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
    (0,0)
;
```

This leads to:

[image]

If you want to keep the label and the arrow on the left side, you may want to use `v_` syntax

```
\draw
    (0,2) to [voltage source, v_=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
    (0,0)
;
```

The result:

[image]

After the comment from the package author, here it follows an example which shows how to use the different syntax the package provides:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw
    (0,0) to [voltage source, v^<=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
    (0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\quad
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,0) to [voltage source, v_<=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
    (0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\quad
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,0) to [voltage source, v^>=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
    (0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\quad
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,0) to [voltage source, v_>=$\underline{U}_{in}$]
    (0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Is there an option to change direction without changing from (0,0) -- (0,2) to (0,2) -- (0,0)? For example with resistors it should work.

Comment: @Michael12342345: I'm not aware of any options for that, but it may be the case. Have you tried with resistors?

Comment: The syntax of v is one of the following: v^>=... (above the element, in the direction of the path), v^<=... (above the element, in the opposite direction), v_>=... (below the element, in the direction), v_<=...

Comment: @kenshin: True! After a couple of years I already forgot few tricks. I will update later the answer. Thanks `:)`

Comment: @kenshin: that's right. But it does not work with voltage source? I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino:
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
   \draw
    (0,0) to [R, v=$U$]
    (0,2) to [R, v>=$U$]
    (0,4)
   ;
  \end{circuitikz}
 \end{document}

Comment: @Michael12342345 Works for me: \documentclass[tikz]{article} \usepackage{circuitikz} \begin{document} \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to [R, v<=$U$] (0,2) to [R, v>=$U$] (0,4) (2,0) to [V, v<=$U$] (2,2) to [V, v>=$U$] (2,4)  ; \end{circuitikz} \end{document}

Comment: @kenshin: it works! I don't know why it didn't work a couple of hours ago.